# Using ng-grid templates in angular

Tags: javascript, angularjs, ng-grid

Need thy help in this hour of need.

I have an issue in which I need to show a ng-grid data related to projects

The status of projects should not be shown to other users. say for Example, if the projectManager "Andrew" has logged in (this is set in $scope.currUsername) he should see the status of projects P1 and P3, the others should see this as "Unknown". The status should be shown to their corresponding projects. I need to use templates for this. Please help.

```
$scope.GridItems = {
data: 'myData',
enableRowSelection: true,
enableSorting: true,
enableCellEditOnFocus: true,
multiSelect: false,
columnDefs: [{
  field: 'projectId',
  enableCellEdit: false
}, {
  field: 'projectStatus',
  enableCellEdit: true,
  enableCellEditOnFocus: true,
   editableCellTemplate: $scope.eTemplate
}, {
  field: 'projectManager',
  enableCellEdit: false
}]
};
```

Plunker Link:  http://plnkr.co/edit/EzBKns?p=preview